# What Sign Language developed among orphans/homeless children using the environment as a base for the signs?

Tags: sign-languages

I remember in one of my linguistics classes, a rather complex sign language (perhaps in Brazil, if I recall correctly) exists among, I believe, deaf children homeless children/orphans on the street. I believe that researchers, for quite a while, had much trouble figuring it out, but a breakthrough was made when they figured out that the signs we're patterned after the shape of streets on signs such as subway or bus maps.

Unfortunately, that is all that I can remember about the subject, and I don't even know how accurate my information is. And so I ask: where is this type of sign language used and what is it's story / what is unique about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you mean [Nicaraguan Sign Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicaraguan_Sign_Language)? I don't know about sign patterns, but that's a language of particular interest because of its spontaneous development, unlike many others.

Comment: This may be it... perhaps my brain manufactured that little bit about maps.

Comment: I was also going to suggest NSL but I also had not heard the various factoids you mentioned but as Stas says it's interesting because it's believed to be a spontaneous invention rather than derived from another sign language.

Answer (score 5):

There are several examples of sign languages that have been invented de novo. Notably, [Nicaraguan Sign Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicaraguan_Sign_Language), [Al-Sayyid Bedouin Sign Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Sayyid_Bedouin_Sign_Language) and other [Village Sign Languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Village_sign_language). In isolation, when deaf children are not exposed to either a signed or spoken language (which is remarkably common even in developed countries) they invent their own [home sign systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_sign). See [here](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/139/is-nicaraguan-sign-language-the-only-language-born-from-nothing/6462#6462) for a related question.